# How to fix dependencies for upgrading Docker engine?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am creating a docker-compose for a express.js application that uses redis and mysql. I am doing this on a distro of Linux Mint.

When I run

```
docker-compose up
```

I get

```
ERROR: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.22, server: 1.18)
```

So the first thing I did was try downgrading my version of compose but I cant do that because it doesn't support my compose file. So the next thing I tried is changing the API version.

```
export COMPOSE_API_VERSION=auto
```

Then after running docker-compose up I got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 124, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 41, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 121, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 92, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 120, in docker_client
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 166, in __init__
docker.errors.InvalidVersion: API versions below 1.21 are no longer supported by this library.
[25236] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

So at this point I changed the API version to something that it would support so I ran.

```
export COMPOSE_API_VERSION=1.22
```

and then I wanted to upgrade the docker engine so I ran this command.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade docker-engine
```

and I got this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 docker-engine : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but 1.14ubuntu1 is to be installed
                 Depends: lsb-base (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu7) but 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6mint1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.97) but 2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libltdl7 (>= 2.4.6) but 2.4.2-1.7ubuntu1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So far I cant find anything on how to fix these dependencies so I am wondering what I am doing wrong here and how do I get this application up and running with Docker?

I will include my docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile below.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
volumes:
services:
 web:
    build: .
    command: "PORT=3002 node bin/www"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app/
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mysql
 redis:
    image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'
    environment:
        - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
        - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
        - /path/to/redis-persistence:/bitnami
 mysql:
     image: mysql:5.7
     container_name: mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
         - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=goon
         - MYSQL_DATABASE=TERRA_TEST
         - MYSQL_DATABASE=TERRA_DEV
     ports:
         - "33061:3306"
volumes:
    appconf:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

Run apt-get update

Run apt-get install curl -y

Run curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x

Run apt-get install -y nodejs

Run apt-get install -y git

run apt-get install npm -y

Run git clone https://github.com/sdrafahl/TerraServer.git

ADD configKeys.json TerraServer/

WORKDIR /TerraServer

run npm install

EXPOSE 3002

CMD PORT=3002 node bin/www
```

Docker Info:

```
Containers: 3
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 15
Server Version: 18.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 39
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-53-generic
Operating System: Linux Mint 18.1
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.756GiB
Name: shane-OptiPlex-980
ID: NAAR:UM5J:CQRX:QTJM:NFU4:IQWP:64XZ:SB4X:UEMR:X7S2:MEQ7:PG34
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: i recommend removing the docker completely if you played with it and install again, the same way as in their docs

Comment: I tried doing that just now and it didn't change anything unfortunately. @MazelTov

Comment: i told you to do it by the docs... https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/#prerequisites ... again, try to follow the steps, see that first step is unistalling old docker version that is named `docker-engine` and the new one is named `docker-ce`

Comment: you should also post output of `docker info`

Comment: When I switched to another machine it seemed to work better. I think the other machine had some problem beyond this because I followed those steps and didn't work like I said. However now I am getting a different issue. @MazelTov

-> " ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"PORT=3002\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project."

Answer (score 0):

The `docker-engine` package is old, possibly from your distribution vendor rather than docker. I'd recommend following the steps to install `docker-ce` directly from docker.

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/